# Improper Resource Shutdown or Release -Veracode CWE 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, veracode

when I ran the scan from veracode , i found the issue like Improper Resource Shutdown or Release , i tried finding the result from other blogs but i didn't get the solution.
below is my code which is pointing at the issue. please suggest if i need to change/alter the code

```
private sealed class StreamWriter : IDisposable
{
    private MemoryStream memoryStream;
            

            private StreamWriter()
            {
              //Pointing the Improper Resource Shutdown or Release here
              memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            }

            ~StreamWriter()
            {
                this.Dispose(false);
            }

            private void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (memoryStream != null)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Dispose();
                        memoryStream = null;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You did not say if the above code is still being flagged by Veracode. Is it still?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue on Veracode

Comment: Has anyone got some solution for this ?